# Does the Gluglug ThinkPad X200 work with Ubuntu?

Tags: lenovo, ssd, ram, thinkpad, compatibility

I'm looking at buying [the Lenovo ThinkPad X200 from Gluglug](http://shop.gluglug.org.uk/product/libreboot-x200/) and they say they have Libreboot so you can install any OS, but I'm wondering if the hardware would work with Ubuntu, and if so, which version?

Can I install the newest update and it will work, or an older one? Do the RAM and HD specs matter? (I'm thinking about 2GB of RAM and 120 GB SSD)

Answer (score 1):

The Libreboot X200 comes with Trisquel GNU/Linux pre-installed. http://shop.gluglug.org.uk/about/

Trisquel is based on Ubuntu. Trisquel 7 "LTS" is based on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I believe. My understanding is that Trisquel is Ubuntu with every last bit of non-Free software ripped out (plus other features like its own "...customized version of the GNOME Flashback desktop environment"). https://trisquel.info/en/wiki/documentation See also the wikipedia entry for Trisquel.

Given the above, I would not foresee any problems running Ubuntu, though I cannot advise on current Ubuntu RAM requirements.

Comment: I'm writing this on an X200s. Officially they take 4Mb of RAM. Unofficially they take 8Gb.

Answer (score 1):

I've been running Lubuntu on an X200 for several years, not as my main computer, but as a frequently used backup. Upgraded through several new releases. It works great! Used for web browsing primarily, used Thunderbird for some time but stopped in favor of web mail, occasionally use LibreOffice, occasionally Slack, Pinta for light image editing...

I believe I have 5GB RAM though (1GB + 4 GB chips). I have the original (non-SSD) drive in it. Highly recommended, but I can't speak to whether 2GB is enough for a tolerable experience.

It took very little tweaking when I first set it up, and I've had no trouble during release upgrades. I *think* I initially had trouble getting it to work properly with the WiFi chip (not a driver issue, but a user interface issue that prevented me from seeing a list of networks to connect to) -- but I think that was resolved several revisions ago. (Also possible I'm remembering a different laptop, though.)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to thinkwiki.org, which is a great source when using Linux on Thinkpads.

Especially, this page http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Installing_Ubuntu_9.10_%28Karmic_Koala%29_on_a_ThinkPad_X200 seems to suggest X200 should work just fine with Ubuntu (well, it is an outdated version of Ubuntu, but newer versions should work at least as well).